# yii2 resize images maintaining aspect ratio with Imagine

Tags: yii2, image-resizing, php-imagine

I got this code in yii2:

```
Image::thumbnail($path, 100, 100)->save($thumbnail, ['quality' => 50]);
```

I thought that it will resize the original image maintaining the aspect ratio.
But it just creates a box...
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use like that:

```
use Imagine\Image\Box;

Image::frame($path)
->thumbnail(new Box(100, 100))
->save($thumbnail, ['quality' => 50]);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I just did! :)

`use Imagine\Gd;
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\BoxInterface;

...

$photo = $imagine->open($path);
$photo->thumbnail(new Box(1200, 1200))->save($path, ['quality' => 90]);`



Thank you for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

I am using like this in Yii2 and it works fine.
It also keeps the aspect ratio perfect releted to width.

```
use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Image\Box;

 ...

$imagine = Image::getImagine()
->open($resizeImagePath)
->thumbnail(new Box(120, 120))
->save($thumbnailImagePath, ['quality' => 90]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple code to maintain the aspect ratio of an image.

```
use yii\imagine\Image;
```

.................................................................

```
public function doResize($imageLocation, $imageDestination, Array $options = null)
{
    $newWidth = $newHeight = 0;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageLocation);

    if(isset($options['newWidth']) || isset($options['newHeight']))
    {
        if(isset($options['newWidth']) && isset($options['newHeight']))
        {
            $newWidth = $options['newWidth'];
            $newHeight = $options['newHeight'];
        }

        else if(isset($options['newWidth']))
        {
            $deviationPercentage = (($width - $options['newWidth']) / (0.01 * $width)) / 100;

            $newWidth = $options['newWidth'];
            $newHeight = $height - ($height * $deviationPercentage);
        }

        else
        {
            $deviationPercentage = (($height - $options['newHeight']) / (0.01 * $height)) / 100;

            $newWidth = $width - ($width * $deviationPercentage);
            $newHeight = $options['newHeight'];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        // reduce image size up to 20% by default
        $reduceRatio = isset($options['reduceRatio']) ? $options['reduceRatio'] : 20;

        $newWidth = $width * ((100 - $reduceRatio) / 100);
        $newHeight = $height * ((100 - $reduceRatio) / 100);
    }

    return Image::thumbnail(
        $imageLocation, 
        (int) $newWidth, 
        (int) $newHeight
    )->save(
        $imageDestination,
        ['quality' => isset($options['quality']) ? $options['quality'] : 100]
    );
}
```

You can use it, like:

```
(new TheClass)->doResize($imageLocation, $imageDestination, [
    'quality' => 70,
    'reduceRatio' => 50
]);

// or like this
(new TheClass)->doResize($imageLocation, $imageDestination, [
    'quality' => 70,
    'width' => 500,
]);

// or like this
(new TheClass)->doResize($imageLocation, $imageDestination, [
    'quality' => 70,
    'height' => 500,
]);

// and like this (but will break the aspect ratio)
(new TheClass)->doResize($imageLocation, $imageDestination, [
    'quality' => 70,
    'width' => 100
    'height' => 500,
]);
```

Comment: That's cool, but why bother if you alreasy have the box method?

Comment: that's cool but there is an error in your examples.
have to be:
`(new TheClass)->doResize($imageLocation, $imageDestination, [
    'quality' => 70,
    'newWidth' => 100
    'newHeight' => 500,
]);`